# What tool to use for vertex intersection of three lines? Stuck on this

Tags: vertex-groups

I hope this puzzle here finds you well. I hear tell this question has been asked and answered. If you are aware of that, please point me to a link that demonstrates as such. I can't find anything close. So here goes again:

I have three lines that need to intersect into a single vertex, but each line has a position on a circle that must also move without distorting the shape of the circumference. The picture shows a planar shape. There is no volume. I intend to extrude that later on.

Going backwards with boolean operations has proven unreliable because later artifacts interfere with the next steps in the design. There has to be a tool method or math function that will let me do this. I have tried loop cuts, knife tool, etc and then reduced down to planar space, but I still get a slight goof in the circle or straightness of the lines no matter how I approach this.

Has anyone encountered this kind of sub-d surface modification before? In AutoCad there is a trim utility where you can select a line segment as a knife edge (so to speak) and then the target segment gets split where they cross...

But I can't figure this one out and I bet it is something simple.[image]

Comment: Could you just subdivide line C, B, A and then Alt + M to merge the 3 vertices?

Comment: Unfortunately that doesn't take into account the offset of the vertexes on the top and bottom of the circle. But thanks for trying. I know of course I have to introduce a vertex along each line at some point anyway. Subdivision may be the first step that you have hit on, but what to do next has me stumped still.

Comment: Marking the question I have posted as duplicate without referring the original question accomplishes nothing. Duarte - I would love to see the answer and not just a duplication indicator. So for the sake of explaining how it is different I will tell you this - it is different in every single last way since I see nothing resembling it anywhere else in the database. Care to share something a little more meaningful?

Comment: Ryan - they mutually average the sum of their distances and distort the original shapes involved. But thanks for the reply. Duarte marked my question as duplicate without referring the answer. Which makes zero sense. I have looked for the duplicate question and answer to no avail. I am still stuck on this.

Comment: Well - I take that back. A link has appeared at the top of the question I hadn't previously noticed before. So thanks for whoever placed it there.